# Using service principal to access Azure blob storage but get error "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: python, azure

ClientSecretCredential.get_token failed: Authentication failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

I've tried to set up http-proxy or using connection_verify=false. And neither of these helps.

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

 os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "**********" 

proxies = {
            "http": "*****************",
            "https": "*****************"
        }

# Tenant ID for your Azure Subscription
TENANT_ID = "e4c9****-****-****-****-230b****57fb"

# Your Service Principal App ID
CLIENT = "3bee****-****-****-****-b0b8****f7a4"

# Your Service Principal Password
KEY = "*******************"

ACCOUNT_NAME = "storagetest789"

CONTAINER_NAME = "newcontainer"

RESOURCE = "https://storage.azure.com/"

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT, KEY)
blobService = BlobServiceClient( "https://{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(ACCOUNT_NAME), credential=credentials, session = session, proxies=proxies, connection_verify=False)

print("\nList blobs in the container")

container = blobService.get_container_client(CONTAINER_NAME)
for blob in container.list_blobs():
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)

print("\nOutput test.txt")
blob = container.get_blob_client("test.txt")
print(blob.download_blob().readall())
```

Comment: Do you have some intermediate http-proxy in between? looks like a problem with broken up https-connection.

Comment: I tried to have http-proxy by using either os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"]  = "**********" or blob_service_client =  BlobServiceClient(                                                  "https://{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(ACCOUNT_NAME), credential=credentials, session = session, proxies=proxies, connection_verify=False) @burna. And it doesn't seem to be working. I am not sure if connection_verify is a right parameter here or not. I found it from https://githubmemory.com/repo/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/20883?page=1

Comment: You need to add the connection_verify argument to ClientSecretCredential as well - although this is a potential securityrisk and you should try to add your intermediate-proxy-CA to your local certificate store.

Comment: @burna I added connection_verify, however it didn't work. And I am still getting the same error. Any thought? I want to get it work first, and will try your recommendation intermediate-proxy-CA. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you please refer this may it helps SO THREAD :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995116/using-service-principal-to-access-azure-blob-storage

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT it's not talking about proxy, and did refer to it.